# Facebook like popup has inverted opacity settings (mouseover/mouseout)

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I have a strange problem with my facebook like button.

Normally, when you click 'like' on a site, you get a popup for a comment.  This popup has 100% opacity on mouseover, but reduced opacity on mouseout.

However, on my site, this is reversed.  I get 100% opacity on mouseout, and reduced opacity on mouseover.  Obviously, this makes it difficult to use.

Here's my site: http://notts-squash.co.uk/results.html?table=teams&idd=440&season=10&social=true. (To test on other pages, add &social=true to the URL.)

Many thanks in advance!  This has been confusing me for weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS from `widget72.css` is causing the transaprency:

```
.at300b:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

You could change your CSS file to :

```
.at300b:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

As long as your CSS file comes after `widget72.css` (which I assume your are hot-linking to) then this should fix the problem. Otherwise you can add `!important` to the code in your CSS file.

#### Edit

If you wanted the children to have the `opacity: 0.8` (in the pop-up) when you are not hovering then you could try the following:

```
.at300b > * {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.at300b:hover, .at300b:hover > * {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is a bit of a hack but would work incase you never find why you are getting this behavour.

Comment: Well it's a hack, but it seems to be doing the job!  Many thanks.

Comment: No problem, you could also try re-ordering your css files / plugins and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure it out as of yet, however, first thing I'd recommend is to change from fbml to html5 style tags for the like plugin.  If that doesn't work, try taking the like plugin out of the complexity of the results.html page and place into a page with minimal HTML elements.  If that works, then you will need to start with a bare bones version of the results.html page and start adding in element/block of HTML at a time until the plugin breaks.  This will tell you what HTML is causing problems with the like plugin.

Comment: OK.  I've put an HTML5 version here: http://notts-squash.co.uk/results.html?table=teams&idd=463&season=10&social=true&html5=true

Comment: That has solved the original problem (opacity now 100% always), although it now doesn't integrate so well with the other addthis buttons, and likes don't seem to contribute to the total number of shares...

Comment: It seems the HTML5 solution is reliant on an iframe, which stops AddThis from tracking likes (https://www.addthis.com/help/client-api#tracking-likes), so not ideal...